# Почему не работает линейный градиент в ие 11?

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, в ие 11 не работает линейный градиент, вот код

```
ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0984c2', endColorstr='#0d72b9');
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0984c2, #0d72b9);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0984c2, #0d72b9);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0984c2, #0d72b9);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#0984c2, #0d72b9);
background: linear-gradient(#0984c2, #0d72b9);
```

градиент просто не рисуется. Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

Еще в ие 11 не работает свойство transform, вот код

```
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 225deg);
-ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 225deg);
-moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 225deg);
-o-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 225deg);
transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 225deg);
```

Мне подсказали, что 3d не работает в ие. Что посоветуете в таком случае? 3d точно убирать не буду, так как с добавлением третьего измерения улучшается качество прорисовки

Answer (score 2):

1) Поставь в конец класса и/или блока:

```
ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0984c2', endColorstr='#0d72b9');
```

2) Попробуй поставить данный `meta`:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>
```